What should my AM signal look like in the frequency domain?
I'm currently making a simple diode AM modulator circuit alongside 2 oscillators. I'm kind of satisfied with what the time domain results look like but I don't think the the results show a proper double sideband in the frequency domain and I'm not sure how to fix it.signals in time domain

Looks like you're just adding the output signals from two generators and rectifying the result. This is not a AM modulator stage.

@Raonoke it actually is! Filter the higher harmonics, and you've got yourself a mixer that way. However, for that to work, the carrier frequency must be much higher than the message signal bandwidth.

Where is node V(n009)? We can guess, but it's better to be clear about the labels. Why is the bandpass filter centered about 50 kHz when the carrier is near 20 kHz? Why is the lowpass filter corner frequency for the modulation lower than the modulation frequency? Why are you using ±4.5 V power supplies when you should be using ±10 V or higher for the LM741 (there are much better opamps available these days). Zoom in around the carrier frequency on the output and you will see what you should be expecting (carrier frequency and the sidebands).

V(n009) is at the output of the mixer, I'll label my outputs better next time. I retuned the bandpass and the output look so much better now thanks! Also Im using 741s because they were the only one available at the local store


What should my AM signal look like in the frequency domain?

Exactly as the message signal looks in the frequency domain, but shifted up to the carrier frequency.
Depending on whether you want to suppress the carrier or not, with a peak at the carrier frequency.
It's impossible to tell (at least for me) whether you've achieved that – the logarithmic frequency axis makes comparing the baseband signal with the modulated signal impossible.
However, there's something that looks suspicious: your carrier has a frequency that lies clearly within the message signal bandwidth. That can't be, the carrier frequency must be much higher.
Also, literally any other Opamp than the 741, please! That is really a garbage opamp that we just keep around to scare students (i.e., to illustrate all the effects you don't want to have in an opamp).

After some experimenting it seems like they end up looking similar because theyre connected and somehow bleeding into each other? I disconnected them and the oscillator outputs looked as expected now. Also I retuned the LC circuit in the modulator and now the output looks as expected. Whats wrong with 741? its the one everyone from my class is using because its the only one available in the local store

@ZoeStarlight The LM741 is a 50+ year old design (1968). In its day it was pretty good due to ease of use, however I never used it for design since the LM318 was superior as well as the MA332, and the LF356 filled in for low bias current requirements. The LM741 suffers from low slew-rate, output swing is not even close to rail-to-rail, low bandwidth, DC specifications are less than good. However, if it's the only opamp available to you, then you are relegated to using it.

@ZoeStarlight one of the most popular questions on this site explains what's wrong with the 714. qrk is absolutely right with all they said! You can add "absurdly high supply voltage" and "very bad noise", "extreme offset errors" to the things that matter to you here. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/304521/reasons-not-to-use-a-741-op-amp/304522#304522

For example, your circuilt already fails because you have too little supply voltage for the LM714. Sure, you can buy more batteries or a larger power supply, but to work with an audio line level signal, you could also save yourself the effort and buy an opamp that works with a single supply (instead of a bipolar supply), and works with a reasonable supply voltage (like 4.5V is!) instead of +10 V and -10V or more!

That modulator seems to have serious distortion.
Compare what you have (left) with what you want (right)


The rightmost plot shows a carrier 100% modulated by a 1kHz (approx) sine wave. If modulation is less than 100%, you'll have more than 6dB amplitude separation between carrier and two sidebands.
It appears that a DC offset is missing from the *MessageSignal source.

How do I add a DC offset?

With AC coupling to 2 inputs, you'd add a DC offset to the diode to compensate its DC forward voltage (perhaps about 0.65V) It can help improve modulator distortion of even-order harmonics of MessageSignal when transposed to the carrier. Ideally, you want only a lower sideband and an upper sideband with no other sidebands further out from the carrier (when MessageSignal is a sine wave).
